# Defining a class inside a method of another class

Tags: java

I have a class A. I define another class B within a method (even main) of the class A and class B can access all the variables within the scope of the method it is defined in. What is the terminology for such classes (as B)? Some people have been saying Nested classes or Inner classes but IIRC, those are the classes where they have another class as their data members (kinda like composition in C++).

The second part of my question is that some people have been saying that when you have a class defined within a method of another class, then the variables of the first class (A) that are accessed by the later class (B) need to be declared final. Is this to be followed strictly and why so?

Comment: I thunk you are talking about an Annonymous inner class.

Comment: I think you have 2 questions here and should split appropriately

Comment: They are related to the same topic, so...

Answer (score 0):

According to the Java Language Specification these are ["local classes"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.3):

> A local class is a nested class (§8 (Classes)) that is not a member of
>   any class and that has a name (§6.2, §6.7).

or ["anonymous [inner] classes"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.), which are just the ones that don't have a name (*e.g.* `Interface x = new Interface() { ...`).

These are special cases of [inner classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3) which is generally what I've heard people refer to them as.

As for your second question, ["Any local variable, formal parameter, or exception parameter used but not declared in an inner class must either be declared final or be effectively final (§4.12.4), or a compile-time error occurs where the use is attempted."](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3)  So it is a compile-time error if you try to access non-final *local* variables.  Obviously this part must be followed strictly if you want your class to compile.

I have not personally heard the advice that you should not access non-final *fields* of the enclosing class, and I'm pretty sure it's allowed.  While arguments could be made that fields should be final unless they can't be, I don't see any stylistic reason this should be more important in inner classes.  There is a technical difference that accessing a field from an inner class may cause the compiler to create and call synthetic getters and setters, but this is generally a minor performance concern.